# Woocommerce - Remove item from cart, not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Steps to recreate the issue:

1) Navigate to Collections
2) Select a product
3) Add to cart
4) Navigate to the cart
5) Try removing the item from the cart

The website can be viewed at: http://52.76.138.120

I have tried with the default theme as well, but I am facing the same issue.
Woocommerce version: 2.6.4
Wordpress version: 4.5.4

Comment: If you open the developers tools included in your browser, you will see that you have 2 major errors and one of them is affecting the woocommerce cart script. **This is a related theme issue.** The best thing is to contact theme author support pages to solve this opening a support ticket (as this kind of questions are off topic here on stackOverFlow).

Comment: The same issue does not occur on demo link that we setup, it works fine there, even though the same error show up. Also the same issue is occurring even with the default theme.

Comment: I am running a lot of woocommerce web sites for clients and for me. I don't have this problems. You have a conflicting javascript/jquery problem related to a theme or a plugin… Deactivate all plugins but not woocommerce and switch on default theme. Update wordpress… you will see this problem is gone…

Comment: @AnujChhabria As I can see you fixed the problem. I have the same problem like you had with my theme I am using. Can you tell me how you fixed it?